# Quadratic JPanel in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Basicly i've got this setup

```
    | JFrame with BorderLayout   |
    | -------------------------- |
    | JPanel with GridBagLayout  |
    | JPanel with NullLayout     |
```

The JFrame is resizable. The JPanel with GridBagLayout contains itselt gain JPanels and looks basicly like this

```
    |Obj|Obj|Obj|
    |Obj|Obj|Obj|
    |Obj|Obj|Obj|
```

The Grid should be quadratic.

If I resize the window, the components will be adjusted automaticly and because of this, the Grid looses it's qudratic dimension and becomes an rectangel.

I can prevent this by writing my own layout manager. So my question to you: is there another possibility to enforce a quadratic grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `GridBagLayout`, consider using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

You can also use  a `null` layout which sets width and height of each component as the width or height divided by either number of rows or columns (depending on how you want to go about it), and set the initial `x` and `y` to values according to this:

`(total width % number of columns) / 2`

and the others to simply 
`initialX + cellWidth * (col - 1)` and 
`initialY + cellWidth * (row - 1)`.

Put this code into your `componentResized(ComponentEvent e){...}` 
method of your middle `JPanel`'s `ComponentListener`, and cycle through your cells (panels) setting their bounds. This might be a slow / manual way but you'll have complete control of exactly how you want them to resize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i can't use an external layoutmanager. doing it manual with null-layout is only the last way to solve it ;)

Comment: i've searched a long time for a function the layoutmanagers for this. the easiest thing will be to implement it by hand. thank you

Comment: Wish I had an easy answer for you. Do consider `MigLayout` though, it's really handy.

Comment: For similar problems i've bookmarked MigLayout. But in this task I'm unable to use external libs. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at samples on `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/index.html` there are GridBagLayoutDemo and SpringGridDemo that might solve your problem. Or the last escape, make your window non-resizable (bad!) like in the GridLayoutDemo...

Comment: GridBagLayoutDemo/SpringGridDemo doesn't enfoce square JPanels. If I resize the window to certain size, the fields are rectangle